# Proving convergence of improper integral, g(t)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I want to prove convergence of the improper integral,

$$\int_1^\infty g(t) dt$$
Where $g(t)$ is given by: $g(t)=(\frac{1-e^{-2t^2}}{t^2})$ , $t\neq0$

I have thought about using different tests, but I keep getting stuck at the fact that as t approaches zero from the right hand side, the function value increases towards infinity, so I can't figure out a limit from the right hand side.

I hope you can help.

Best regards,
Christoffer

Comment: $0$ is not part of the integration domain so why do you want to compute that limit?

Comment: $0< \frac{1-e^{-t^2}}{t^2} < \frac{1}{t^2}$ which is integrable on $[1,\infty)$, so by comparison, your integral converges.

Comment: @LL3.14 Please give that as an answer, things are getting a little wooly.

Comment: You are absolutely right!
I mistakenly thought that zero was part of the integral, since I had to calculate g(0) in another assignment.

Answer (score 0):

$0<\frac{1−e^{−t^2}}{t^2} < \frac{1}{t^2}$ which is integrable on $[1,∞)$, so by comparison, your integral converges.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the integrand, it can be rewritten as 
$$
f(t) = 2 \int_{0}^{1} e^{-2t^2x} dx
$$
So the whole expression (with $\varepsilon \to \infty$)
$$
L = 2 \int_{1}^{\varepsilon}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-2xt^2}dxdt = 2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{\varepsilon} e^{-2xt^2}dt dx
$$
Use the $\texttt{erf}$ function for the second integral:
$$
L = \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}[\texttt{erf}(\varepsilon) - \texttt{erf}(1)]
$$
Now, compute the simple integral, and then take the limit as $\varepsilon \to \infty$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: I am unfortunately unfamiliar with the erf function, but the problem was solved by looking at the integral again (sorry for the inconvenience!). 

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ChristofferMadsen https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=error%20function

Answer (score -1):

We use the special function $$\text {erf}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$ and the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\text{erf}(x)=1.$ First we integrate from 1 to $b$ and then we take the limit as $b \to \infty$. Integration by parts gives $$\int_1^b\frac{1-e^{-2t^2}}{t^2}dt=\int_1^b(-\frac{1}{t})'(1-e^{-2t^2})$$
$$=\frac{-(1-e^{-2t^2})}{t}|_1^b+4\int_1^be^{-2t^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{-(1-e^{-2b^2})}{b}+1-e^{-2}+\frac{4}{\sqrt 2}\int_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2 b}e^{-u^2}du$$ after making the substitution $u=\sqrt 2 t$. Thus the inegral is
$$\frac{-(1-e^{-2b^2})}{b}+1-e^{-2}+\frac{4}{\sqrt 2}(\int_0^{\sqrt 2 b}e^{-u^2}du-\int_0^{\sqrt 2}e^{-u^2}du)$$ $$=\frac{-(1-e^{-2b^2})}{b}+1-e^{-2}+2\sqrt{\pi}(\text{erf}(\sqrt 2 b)-\text{erf}(\sqrt 2))$$ Taking the limit as $b \to \infty$, the given integral converges to $$1-e^{-2}+2\sqrt\pi(1-\text{erf}(\sqrt 2)).$$